# After nuget package uninstal ps script modifies project, the project has to be manually saved

Tags: visual-studio-2010, project, uninstallation, nuget, nuget-package

I'm a bit confused about what I need to do in a nuget uninstall script when I am removing items from the project's xml. First, the basic scripts below work - in that they correctly remove items that I'd added in the install script. But when the uninstall process finishs, the project is still marked dirty and has to be saved. I'd like that to be all taken care of when I'm done. Here is the code I've got:

```
Import-Module (Join-Path $toolsPath msbuild.psm1)

#
# Get the project
#

$project = Get-Project
$buildProject = Get-MSBuildProject

#
# Next, add the import statements
#

$imports = $buildProject.XML.Imports | ? {([System.IO.FileInfo] $_.Project).Name -eq "LINQTargets.targets" }
if ($imports)
{
  foreach ($i in $imports)
  {
     $buildProject.XML.RemoveChild($i)
  }
}

$project.Save() #persists the changes
$buildProject.Save()
```

After my nuget package has been uninstalled, I then have to "save" the project. How can I avoid that? I'd like it to be left in a clean state so the user has no option of not-saving the file after the uninstal (as that would leave the project file in a very inconsistent state!).

Comment: Some more investigation on my part: this might be a nuget "bug" - if I don't save the solution file and just discard the changes then the my additions are gone, but the items that nuget added (like content files) are still present... so this may not be my issue at all.